# docker commit doesn't apply changes to newly created docker image

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-container

I have a folder named `Test` and the files in folder are as follows --

Test
  - test_002.sql
  - Dockerfile
  - docker-compose.yml

the content of `Dockerfile` as follows --

```
FROM mysql:5.6.40  
COPY . /Test
```

contents of `docker-compose.yml` is as below --

```
version: '3'  
services:
   test_db:
      build: .
      image: test_env
      container_name: test_env
      tty: true
      volumes: 
        - .:/Test
      environment: 
        MYSQL_DATABASE: 'test_db'
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'test_root_pwd'
        MYSQL_PASSWORD:  'test_pwd'
        MYSQL_USER: 'root'
```

Now, I will explain a sequence of steps that I have done
step1:

```
docker-compose up --build
```

This has created a new docker container which is up and running
step2:

Then, I got inside the docker container `docker exec -it <container-ID> bash`
step3:
Inside the docker container i have the mysql dump file `test_002.sql` in `Test` folder. I loaded the mysql dump as `mysql -uroot -ptest_root_pwd test_db < Test/test_002.sql`. Then the test database is loaded with all the tables and test data into tables.
       *step3_check:*
Checking if step3 loaded mysql dump test data into the empty db (created when docker-compose up is executed in step 1)--

```
mysql -uroot -psecret  
use test_db;
show tables;
```

I can see all the tables inside `test_db`and test data inside each table coming from mysql dump file(`test_002.sql`). So far so good.

step4:
Now I wanted to create a new image with the tables and test data loaded inside the test_db. So I did `docker container commit <container-ID> <Image:Tag>`. This created a new image (which supposedly should contain a `test_db` with all the tables and test data)

step5:
I push the newly created docker image `Image:Tag` to dockerhub.

step6:
From a different machine I pulled this docker image `Image:Tag` and ran a  docker container based of that newly pulled image `docker run Image:Tag`. Then a new docker container is created up and running like in step1

step7: In this newly created docker container from step 6, I did the following --

```
mysql -uroot -psecret  
use test_db;
show tables;
```

The result is `Empty set (0.00 sec)`.

Where are all the tables and test data? I thought I loaded into test_db and created a new image with the changes using `docker commit`. Apparently there is no test data in the docker image that i pushed into docker hub.

Any idea why this has happened or any suggestions on how to get the test_db loaded with test data and freeze that as a docker image and pull it from any other machine
In other words if I pull `Image:Tag` from docker hub, all the containers created from that image should have the mysql database called 'test_db' with all tables and test data loaded.

Thanks,

Comment: What are the contents of `/var/lib/mysql` inside both your local container and published image?

Comment: Can you try calling commit with the extra change flag like `docker commit --change`?

Comment: @namokarm docker commit --change <container ID> <Image:Tag> gives a error response from daemon: No such container: `<Image:Tag>`